# Let $f$ be noncostant entire function whose value on real line are real and non negative.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be noncostant entire function whose value on real line are real and non negative.

Prove that all  zeroes of $f$ have even orders

any hint how to approach .how can i connect the order of zeroes to its restriction on real axis

let $f$ have a zero say $z_0$ of order $n$. then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ where $g(z_0)$ is   not zero. now to go from this point ??

Answer (score 2):

$f(z)=z^2+1$ is non constant and entire function which take non negative value on real axis.but it has roots $i,-i$ each one have order 1. is not this a counter example to above question.

Comment: The question was probably about the real zeros. And that $f$ is entire is useless

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens to the sign of $(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ close to $z_0$ if $n$ is odd?

Comment: will u please more elaborate

Comment: If $n$ is odd, can $(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ be non-negative on both sides of $z_0$?

Comment: That argument only seems to work if $z_0$ is real.

Comment: what is mean by both side of $z_0$.on  horizantal line passing $z_0$??

Comment: @Vik78 I think that's natural to assume that, because otherwise, $x^2+1$ has two odd order zeroes.

Comment: @Arthur will u please write ur solution.i am not getting u what u r saying

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f(0)=0$. Since $f$ is nonconstant there is an $n\geq1$ and a function $g$ which is analytic and nonzero in a neighborhood $U$ of $0$, such that
$$f(z)=z^n g(z)\quad(z\in U), \qquad g(0)=:c\ne0\ .$$
As $g(z)=f(z)/z^n$ when $z\ne0$ it follows that $g$ is real for real $z\ne0$, and by continuity it follows that $c\in{\mathbb R}$. WLOG we may assume that $c>0$, so that $g(x)>0$ when $x\in U$. This allows to conclude that
$${\rm sgn}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)={\rm sgn}(x^n)=\bigl({\rm sgn}(x)\bigr)^n\quad(x\in U)\ ,$$
and enforces that $n$ is even.